# How can I add custom fields in Graylog?

Tags: field, graylog, extractor

How can I add custom fields (like on the screenshot)? I’m a beginner in graylog and I can’t found the answer on google. I found a similar topic in the Graylog Community, but it’s closed without solution. I know I need to create an extractor, but even though I’ve read the documentation I don’t understand how I can do it.

I checked in the marketplace, but I think the field I would like to create is specific for my application (I want to show an attribute that exists in my code - username). I just want to know the way to create a field because the regexp I’ll create after.

[image: fields-graylog-screenshot]

Comment: Could you maybe add a sample of your message?

Answer (score 0):

Extractors is the easiest way to do it, once you figure out how to use them. I believe one of the features of extractors is to replace the original data with the extracted item (I think it's called "cut"). Thus, if you can send the data containing the username to Graylog, you can use an extractor to pull this data out and create a custom field containing the extracted usernames. If you have a specific question regarding how to use extractors, feel free to ask; it really is the best choice in this situation.